# xargs call fails when its shell command is specified with a variable

Tags: shell, variables, xargs

I need to have a variable shell command for use in an xargs call.

... xargs -I {} sh -c *command* ...

I find that xargs works when the command is 'literal' but fails when I specify it through a shell variable.

Any suggestion to troubleshoot this?

Below is example code.

```
## xargs call with literal shell command 

# works; creates file abcd1234.txt containing string 'abcd1234'
echo 'abcd1234' | xargs -I {} -n 1 sh -c 'echo {} | grep "\d" > {}.txt'

## xargs call with variable as shell command

# create shell command to give to xargs
cmd1='echo'
cmd2='grep "\d"'
command=${cmd1}' {} | '${cmd2}' > {}.txt'

# returns the literal command that works: echo {} | grep "\d" > {}.txt
echo $command

# fails
echo 'abcd1234' | xargs -I {} -n 1 sh -c $(echo $command)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
echo 'abcd1234' | xargs -I {} sh -c "$command"
```

<sup>Note: I've removed `-n 1` from the command, because it contradicts `-I`, which implies *line-by-line* processing.</sup>

You didn't use double quotes around your command substitution `$(...)`, which made the shell apply word splitting (splitting into tokens by whitespace), which means that *multiple* arguments were placed after the `-c` option rather than a *single* command string.

Aside from that, there's no need to involve a command substitution: direct use of the - double-quoted - variable (`"$command"`) is sufficient.